# Huge latency in the middle of a route between India and Europe

Tags: ping, latency, traceroute

I play on an online gaming Minecraft server. The server is hosted in Europe and I live in India so I get miserable latency (250ms).

A tracert shows that at the 8th hop (in Mumbai) the latency skyrockets. I get the same result multiple times:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix it or find what the problem is.

Also can I fix the packet loss somehow?

Comment: A VPN *could* help, because traffic *may* take a different route. But that’s really just speculation.

Comment: Can you produce a WinMTR or equivalent of the same traceroute -this will provide insights into the nature and cause of the problem.

Comment: @DanielB - probably not.  VPN's typically take a less direct route, which will increase latency, and UDP - which most VPN's use is often dropped before TCP on congested links.   It is conceivable this could help (due to compression or alternative routing, but highly unlikely)

Comment: here is a winMtr http://prntscr.com/cxt8x2

Comment: i dont knwo what winMTR exactly is so I ran the trace for sometime and then stopped it...if that is what you guys wanted..

Comment: From looking at AS6453’s (Tata Communications) Looking Glass, I can see that they have some terrible intra-continental peering. You’re out of luck, sorry.

Comment: @MartinCactus - generally its a good idea to run it for longer then you did, but yes, this gives us some hints.   There are multiple issues - the connection between yourself and your ISP is congested, and this is most likely the cause of your issues.  Note that the best latency is 19ms and the worst is 340ms - that implies your connection is relatively small (maybe its DSL with limited outbound speed ?) .    You may hve software consuming all your bandwidth periodically - but that is the first problem.

Comment: @MartinCactus -   Your providers infrastructure also appears to be struggling to keep up with the load - the packet loss on hops 4 and 5, but not 6-9 indicate the routers are having issues keeping up, or are limiting the number of packets to them.  This may or may not be indicative of the issue.    I don't know about the peering, but what DanielB says rings true, and could be compounding the issue.

Comment: Bottom line - you probably can't do much about the minimum latency, but there are things you may be able to do (change your ISP, get a better connection, control your usage of your link) to improve the maximum latency and possibly packet loss.

Comment: oh, ok..and yes i do have a connection which limits speed after a certain amount of data usage..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from India to France is in the order of 7000km's, which means a return trip time of about 120ms just on that leg - and I imagine that, reverse DNS notwithstanding, hop 7-8 is the backhaul between Mumba an Mareille - in other words, short of moving, you probably can't do a whole lot about the latency.

Its not possible to comment on packet loss until we have more information (a WinMTR will provide packet loss/hop and jitter), but its entirely possible that packet loss is not an issue and the routers are just heavily loaded and dropping/limiting ICMP - this is not uncommon.  If there is a packet loss issue, you would need to speak to your ISP (or change providers) to get it fixed.

Comment: but the server at the 8th hop IS situated in Mumbai..then why am I getting such a latency boost?

Comment: @MartianCactus The name says Mumbai, but it could also mean “this is the router leading to Mumbai”. Without insight into their naming schema, it’s mere speculation.

Comment: @MartinCactus Not according to the speed of light its not.  If you look at hop 8-hop 9, the ostensible latency difference is only about 10ms - there is no way you can travel > 2000+ miles (return trip) in that time.  It must thus be a DNS anomaly.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cxt8x2   winMTR